# How gracefully stop/turn off the vagrant rsync-auto

Tags: vagrant

According to the vagrant official manual, by making any changes to the vagrant environment it recommended to turn off "rsync-auto" before that. Im using it as a background job so "Ctrl+C" is not an option for me now, but the manual doesn't even mentioned how to stop/turn off it at all [https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/rsync-auto.html] so Im looking for a way to make it happen instead of just kill the process directly.

btw
the vagrant version was 2.1.5

Updated Oct 15
and it seems like the file synchronization only happened from the host to the VM, not the other way. is there any way to make it works both way?

Comment: Same question here: How do I stop vagrant rsync-auto correctly?